# How did he know which rose to pick?

Tags: lateral-thinking, story

> One day a wife picked a rose from a magical bush. Little did she know
>   the rose bushed was cursed by a witch and who ever picks a rose from
>   her bush gets turned into a rose and put on the bush. The only way she
>   can get turned back is if her husband picks her as a rose, if he picks
>   the wrong one though he gets turned into a rose also. But here is the
>   thing, the wife has 3 kids and convinced the witch to let her be
>   turned back into a human for the night to see her kids. The next
>   morning he went to the Witch's rose bush and saw 20 roses. After
>   looking at every rose he picks a rose and his wife appears in front of
>   him.

How did he know which rose to pick?

Comment: Yeah, but how did he know she became human for the night?

Comment: Can I edit the title so that 'what' becomes 'which'?

Comment: I think the title "Witch Rose?" would fit.

Comment: How did the husband even know he was supposed to wake up next morning and go to a rosebush and pick a rose in the first place? Did the witch drop in for tea and let him know of the circumstances?

Comment: @MattiaNocerino presumably the kids told the husband, personally I want to know how a rose convince a witch (unless the transformation was not immediate.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

He picked the rose which

> didn't have dew on it.

Because

> his wife had been allowed to be a human for the night, but all the real roses had been out overnight and gathered dew.

Comment: Wow, fast and clean! Good job :)

Comment: My guess is: He knew normal roses would have dew because they are inmobiles and outside. The one with no dew ought to have something special about it since it had no dew despite being outside, he didn't need to know his wife was out or even cursed. He may have taken the one with no dew just to check why it had no dew despite being next to the others.

Comment: @JuanManuel Explaining an answer *which was spoilered for a damn good reason* in a comment *directly below the spoilered answer* is inconsiderate, even plain rude. Please delete the comment.

Comment: @JuanManuel Changing it through rot13 may help so that people can't directly see your comment.