# Literary Haikus

Tags: riddle, knowledge, poetry, literature

Inspired by [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43707/songs-artists-from-haikus), I've created a group of haikus each of which describes a well-known work of literature and its author.

1. > A mighty master
   >   Of small precious jewellery.
   >   A tollman eager.
2. > One half oft brings death,
   >   The other will end the first.
   >   A tollman's doll.
3. > Wibbly-wobbly balls,
   >   Turning round and round and round.
   >   An Arab nation.
4. > For the dozenth time,
   >   A darkness fills up the sky.
   >   A weapon trembling.
5. > A most strange story
   >   Told when the outside is cold.
   >   A weapon waving.
6. > A magic number
   >   Of fighting men armed with guns.
   >   [This answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/42586/5373), mother.
7. > A creature or beast
   >   In a place where such are kept.
   >   For water, use sink ... ?

Partial answers will be upvoted. I'll accept the answer which solves whichever one of the seven is *last* to be solved (and therefore, presumably, the most difficult).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

2.

> War and Peace, Leo Tolstoy -
>  War often brings death; Peace ends war.  Toll's Toy is the doll.

3.

> Wheel of Time series, Robert Jordan -
>  "wibbly wobbly" = timey wimey; wheels "turning round and round"

Comment: Updated to include #2, probably while you were commenting :)

Comment: Yay, good job! You'll get the accepted answer for this :-)

Comment: ... or WILL I? hehe

Answer (score 12):

1.

> Lord of the Rings, Tolkien (Toll Keen)

4.

> Twelfth Night, Shakespeare (Shake Spear)

5.?

> A Winter's Tale, Shakespeare (much less confident than 12th Night, don't think this would be used twice)

6.

> Three Musketeers, Dumas (Dew Mass?)

7.

> Animal Farm, Orwell (Or Well)

Comment: Good job, all correct so far ("ma", not "mass", for #6 - it's meant to work phonetically).

Answer (score 4):

I'll get the first, probably easiest one out of the way, because for now I haven't got any others.

> 1. Lord of the Rings, by JRR Tolkien (Master of the Jewellery, Toll-Keen)